# jQuery - Trying to load everything / an cache issue

Tags: jquery, caching, refresh, loading

**My first problem :** 
I am currently using `$(window).load` to delay the page render in order to load **all** images and then show it.

It does work with all `<img>` tags But **it is not working** with **div tags that have background image**. Lets say I have 30 image on my website template and 10 of them are from `background` specified in CSS.

Using the `$(window).load` function, 20 of those `<img>` images are loaded before the function fires. But the remaining 10 will be loaded when the page starts showing. So the webpage looks very ugly before it is completed.

How can I include those in my `windows.load` function?

**Second problem:**
Because I started making a webpage **from scratch** for the first time, **the pages have a cache issue.** I am going to explain what I mean.

The problem is that after I **change something** in HTML (adding or removing images, etc ... ) When I **try to reload** the page on my browser to **see the changes**, The web page goes into crazy mode and it's messed up. **Unless I do a Full Refresh ( CTRL + F5 )**. It doesn't matter which browser I am using, The page looks messed up after doing either a small or big change in the HTML code.

This is not something normal in my situation. All website on the www are changing their template or part of their page every day/week and It looks so fine everything to enter.
I haven't published my website yet, If I go doing changes on the code every time the user will see weird page.

What's happening ?

Comment: Having to do a full refresh is normal.  Browser caching is normal.  But if your site is not complete and nobody has seen it yet, it does not matter.  Otherwise, the cache typically clears out when the browser is quit & restarted which is why you incorrectly assume it's not an issue for all other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the caching problem you could add a `meta` element that tells the browser not to cache the page :

```
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
```

For your images, you could preload them and only after the images are loaded in the memory allow the browser to execute some script. An approach would look like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var elementsWithBg = $('*').filter(function(){
        return (bg = $(this).css('background-image')) != '' && bg != 'none'; 
    });
    var n = elementsWithBg.length;
    function callback(){
        if(n > 0)
            return;
        ready();
    }
    elementsWithBg.each(function(i,el){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
           n--; 
           callback();
        };
        img.src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)/g,'$1');
    });
});
function ready(){
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much your code is working very well. I don't understand how is the `function ready()` related to the `windows.load` . you never called it in `windows.load` how is it fired then ?

Comment: @xperator : `ready` is called in the `callback` function. After a image loads, the `n` variable holding the images length is decremented. The *if* statement in the `callback` function can be translated to `if(n<=0) ready();` which means that if all the images are loaded, call the `ready` function.

Comment: Regarding the cache problem, I can't use the `NO-CACHE` because my website visitors have slow net and they can't just load everytime. Is there there a way to use a line like that to tell browser to re-cache the page? For example If I change something on the page over time, I just use a line to force browser to re-cache data if the user hasn't seen the new page look yet. Can I approach something like this ?

Comment: If you need to recache only some elements, you can do a trick by adding a random query parameter to the particular resource that you want to recache (such as `img.png?p=12335` or `style.css?r=random`). That will not alter the resource, but will trick the browser into thinking that it's a new resource and force it to download it again.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking at the files locally. Cache control works better over HTTP.

One suggestion that will certainly help: use [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) to greatly reduce the number of images and HTTP calls. Use CSS background whenever possible with this technique.